# Como armar una query recursiva?

Tags: mongodb, graphql

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con Mongo y graphql. Quiero armar una base de usuarios, donde los usuarios puedan tener ambientes, y los ambientes van a tener plantas.

Si yo hago una query para obtener las plantas, puedo ver correctamente sus ambientes

```
query {
  Plantas{
   ambientes{
    nombre
   }
  }
 }
```

Cuando yo hago una query para obtener datos del ambiente, recibo los datos del usuario correctamente

```
query {
  Ambientes{
   user{
    firstName
   }
  }
 }
```

Pero si yo hago una query anidada, la planta tiene en su interior el ambiente que corresponde, pero el usuario me sale en NULL

```
 query {
  Plantas{
   ambientes{
    nombre
    user {
     _id
   }
  }
 }
```

> ESTA ES LA QUERY DONDE NO OBTENGO EL DATO ESPERADO, EL `_id` queda `NULL`. Si yo hago un console.log de plantas, veo que el ambiente que le corresponde a cada planta es un objeto completo con todos los datos del ambiente. En cambio el usuario de ese objeto ambiente, es **solamente** el ID del usuario, y no el usuario completo (en forma de objeto, igual que el ambiente). **Cómo debo armar la query para que traiga los datos como corresponden?**

Dejo a continuacion el código de mi backend. **Creería que el problema está en la última query del resolver (abajo del todo)**

Schema de las plantas

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const plantaSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    origen: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    etapa: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    fecha: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    ambiente:
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Ambiente'
    }
    ,

}, { timestamps: true })

export default model('Planta', plantaSchema)
```

Schema de los ambientes

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const ambienteSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tipo: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    tiempo: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    plantas: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Planta'
        }
    ]},
    {timestamps: true}
)

export default model('Ambiente', ambienteSchema)
```

Schema de los usuarios

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ambientes: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Ambiente'
        }
    ]

},
    { timestamps: true })

export default model('User', userSchema)
```

Estas son las queryes del resolver;

```
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        async Users() {
            return await User.find()
        },
        Users: async () => {
            try {
                const users = await User.find().populate('ambientes')
                return users.map(user => {
                    return {...user._doc,
                            password: null}
                })
            } catch (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        },
        Ambientes: async () => {
            try {
                const ambientes = await Ambiente.find().populate('user plantas')
                return ambientes.map(ambiente => {
                    return {ambiente}
                })
            } catch (err) {
                throw err
            }
        },

        Plantas: async () => {
            try {
                const plantas = await Planta.find().populate('ambiente')
                return plantas.map(planta => {
                    return {planta}
                })
            }
            catch (err) {
                throw err
            }
        }
    },
```